# Converting likelihood equation into R code

Tags: r, equation, bayesian, log-likelihood

I'm working on coding GP model in R and calculating its likelihood function.

I'm having problem to convert the equation below into R code: [image]

I used the code below but I keep getting error message :

```
Error in (t(zlt - olt)) * (zlt - olt) : non-conformable arrays
```

my code is:

```
ConditionalLikelihood <- (-(N/2)) * (log(sig2e)) -(1/(2*(sig2e)))*(t(zlt -olt)) * (zlt- olt) -(sum(T*r)/2) *(log (sig2eta * SEta)) (-1/(2*(sig2e))) * (t(zlt- xb)) * 1/SEta *(zlt- xb)
```

I think it's related to the 2 sum signs. I couldn't find an example shows how to deal with 2 sum signs and follow their structure.

I tried to debug it part by part to check where I went wrong and every time I get to this part , I get the error:

```
(t(zlt -olt)) * (zlt- olt)
```

Any advice will be much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe `%*%` instead of `*`? Assuming you are in fact trying to do vector/matrix multiplications.

Comment: yes you are right !! it's the sign I needed it! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try %*% for matrix multiplication instead of *.

```
(t(zlt -olt)) %*% (zlt- olt)
```